# Already display the player card value but have an error range() integer end argument expected, got list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Whenever I display the `playerscards` I get an error saying

> range() integer end argument expected
>   But `list.below` is in my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def cards(self, handsize):
    global playerscards
    playerscards = []
    for i in range(handsize):
        playerscards.append(str(self.cards[randrange(52)]))
        print playerscards
    return playerscards

def main():
  n=Deck()
  n.cards(playerscards) 
main()

Output:
 for i in range(handsize):
 TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.
```

Comment: How are you calling the `cards` method?

Comment: Thank you for your help i already updated the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. The `range()` function's first positional argument has to be an integer, but you are passing it a list. Where are you passing in `handsize`? Make sure that you are actually passing in what you think you are.